# How to remain space in XSL

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have an XML of the following process

```
<p>
 <contribution>
  <authors><author>
   <surname>Zhengxing</surname> <given-name>Chen</given-name>
  </author> </authors>
 </contribution>
</p>
```

But I need below format. Major problem is in space between surname and given-name. But after converting the file, space is gone.

```
<p>
 <span class="contribution">
  <span class="authors"><span class="author">
     <span class="surname">Zhengxing</span> <span class="given-name">Chen</span>
  </span> </span>
 </span>
</p>
```

Thanks for advance.

Comment: Why don't you add the space yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:element name="p"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="contribution|authors|author|surname|given-name">
    <xsl:element name="span">
        <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is correct. But I need remain space between surname and given-name. It should not change when conversion.

Comment: @Shanmugalakshmi, u need to remove space or retain space? At present this is the out put <span class="surname">Zhengxing</span> <span class="given-name">Chen</span>